# Access Enterprise Architect repository from task

Tags: c#, repository, scheduled-tasks, enterprise-architect

I would like a scheduled task to execute EA application and access its repository.

The task does not depend on whether there are logged in users  or not. It should work in any case.

The task  works whenever there is logged-in user, but does not work if there isn't- then I can execute EA application but cannot connect to its repository.

The following code snippet opens EA application, and connect its repository:

```
//Open EA
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(eaInstallationPath, eapModelPath);  
processInfo.Verb = "runas";
var process = Process.Start(processInfo);  

//Access repository
//problematic line: 
EA.App EAApplication = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("EA.App", "") as EA.App;  
EA.Repository repository = EAApplication.Repository; 
repository.OpenFile(path);
```

The error I get refers to the problematic line :
**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {67F4E0FA-46A7-4255-B084-69A9433D08C3} failed due to the following error: 80080005.**

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to access in the repository?  The standard EA file is an MS Access database with a different extension.  You could write a small application to directly manipulate the tables depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JaneS, Thanks for the great suggestion! Actually I do not think I can use it since I wouldn;t like to modify the DB, but to access the packages and execute package.GetLatest() method. Any other ideas?

Comment: I haven't used the API, but what does `GetLatest()` give you?  I assume it's giving the most recent copy of a particular model?  In what format/object model does it retrieve it?

Comment: @JaneS, The operation indeed provide to the package the latest version from the version control system. I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry :)  My question is, when you call the API what do you need to do with it?  Do you produce a report, or manipulate it in some way?

Comment: @user3165438 I'd say `GetLatest()` actually modifies the local database. But in general it's possible to open a repository silently and apply any operations. The OP should clarify about the errors why connecting the repository fails.

Comment: @user3165438 Also can you give us a small code sample, how you're opening the EA application and connect to the repo, please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Here it is, Thanks.

Comment: @user3165438 The exact exception message could be helpful to diagnose also.

Comment: What is the final resolution? Is any of the answers acceptable? How did you solve it?

Comment: @xmojmr, I still did not manage to accss the repository from a task that works when there is no logged in user. If you have further information please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing EA from a task when no user is logged in is a known problem.
Many have tried, and few have succeeded.

It is possible, and this [whitepaper](http://www.lieberlieber.com/fileadmin/user_upload/White_Paper/2012-1.0-Publication-EA-as-an-unattended-Windows-Service-on-Windows-Server-2008R2-and-high.pdf) from LieberLieber should give you some insight into how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks. The whitepaper seems to claim that it is possible only in case there is a logged in user. Have you succeed to do so?

Comment: @user3165438 I can't spot that this is claimed in the whitepaper. There will be a user but just the one used for running services, check the _preparations_ section in the whitepaper.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far what I have been researching on the topic, it seems, you don't need to start EA explicitly to connect to an existing repository. The `RepositoryClass` class seems to do this automatically under the hood.

In the EA documentation (Automation and Scripting -> ... Tips & Tricks) it [says](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/automation_and_scripting/codesamples.html)

> • An instance of the Enterprise Architect (EA.exe) process is executed when you initialize a new repository object - this process must remain running in order to perform automation tasks; if the main window is visible, you can safely minimize it, but it must remain running

The C# automation sample on my machine contains a snippet that looks as follows.

```
if( m_Repository == null ) {
    m_Repository = new EA.RepositoryClass();
    m_Repository.OpenFile(textBox1.Text);
}
```

There isn't any line of code starting EA as process before obtaining the `Repository` object.

Comment: Thanks. Did you try the code as a scheduled service and succeed? I try it and get the same error, now on `m_Repository = new EA.RepositoryClass();' Any ideas?

Comment: @user3165438 Sorry, no I didn't test this as a scheduled service. It just looked weird to me how you're obtaining the repository object.